# Removing a user from an OpenFire Roster causes both Rosters to be affected

Tags: ios, xcode, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

having a major issue with OpenFire, hopefully one of you guys could help out.

Basically the end goal is to remove user_2 from the roster of user_1 - but making sure that user_1 is still in the roster of user_2.

I've been reading the XMPP protocol documentation and it confirms what i assumed - that only users who subscribe to each other can be in the relevant rosters. If user_1 is removed from user_2's roster, then user_1 is also removed from user_2's roster (sorry for repeating myself).

Is there any way that this can be achieved without both rosters being affected? I'm guessing it's a server side issue and unfortunately i'm not knowledgeable enough to attempt to fix it myself.

Thanks!

Comment: The state of the subscription, which can be 'none', 'to', 'from' or 'both', is not related if a user is in the roster. See also http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#roster-syntax-items-subscription

Answer (score 0):

user_1 and user_2 will always have independent rosters no matter who deletes who from either rosters.

this means that if user_1 deletes user_2 from their roster, user_2 would still have user_1 in their roster.

some clients would automatically remove or hide a contact to which a user a subscription of none (subscription="none"). this would make it appear that either contact can remove themselves from the other person's roster, which is not true.

try testing this out on psi and pidgin to understand what im saying.